# git lfs credential check command

Tags: git, credentials, git-lfs

- Our company has a policy to force us to change passwords every three months. So `git lfs` operation will be broken every three months.
- The problem is that `git` alone uses the default built windows credential mechanism so `git pull` can survive such password-change and only at the very end of `git pull` process the git lfs operation kicks in and then fail, leaving my huge git repo in a messy stage, with hundreds of changed or untracked files.

So, is there any simple git lfs command I can use prior to `git pull`, to check/verify? I tried `git lfs pull` but that one does not ask for credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Our company has a policy to force us to change passwords every three months. So git lfs operation will be broken every three months.

It should not be broken, because Git credentials should use PAT (see "[Creating a personal access token for the command line](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line)"), not Windows passwords.

That way, Windows passwords keep changing, but your PAT remains constant (and can be revoked/replaced at any time).

Comment: I don't know if we use PAT -- _"A personal access token is required to authenticate to **GitHub**"_, while I'm accessing in-house private git that uses the default built *Windows* credential mechanism, which used to be TFS, but now as git.

Comment: Yes, TFS-git has PAT as well. Thanks! Though it is *still* good to know how to check/verify...

Comment: @xpt Apparently so (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/2455). But I missed the TFS part in your original question though.

Comment: Thanks for the update, VonC, accepting yours as the answer as nobody else chipped in so far.

Comment: @xpt https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial says "git lfs track stores the tracked files patterns in .gitattributes": Do you have a .gitattributes, and what is its content?

Comment: @xpt Also, what does  `git lfs env` returns? (https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/901)